# Using git to put a project into a repository

Tags: java, eclipse, git

I have a new project in Eclipse in the directory ProjectDirectory which contains the src, lib, etc. folders. Note that this project has never before communicated with any repository.

I have a git repository https://github.com/myrepo/mygit.git with a username `user` and a password `pass` (note that this is fake info). In that repository, I currently have some files.

I want to do the following.

1. Remove ALL the current contents in the git repository
2. Add the new contents from my Eclipse project into this repository. This should result in no conflicts or no errors whatsoever, since I want to completely replace the current repository with these files.

With specific instructions, what set of commands in the terminal would I write to accomplish this?

Comment: You'd be better off deleting the github repo entirely and starting over by publishing your local repo again.

Comment: what is the command to do this? i want to keep the URL but just delete the contents...

Comment: Follow the steps provided on github to publish a new repository. Or use the github GUI client and make it a one-click endeavor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its fully simple. First go into the directory in terminal where the eclipse project is.

To start putting this under version managment:

```
git init
```

Then add the origin as the git repo ( copy your ssh read+write access from github, this you see when you are loggin in on github and navigates to the actual repositorys directory ):

```
git remote add origin <copied_adress_from_github>
```

So now in the last step you will need to overwrite forced the remote repo with:

```
git push -f origin master
```

You can start commiting, making branches etc... However if on the remote repo there was other branches you want to remove them with:

```
git push origin --delete <branch_name>
```